# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse not working when custom Javascript is present

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Imagelightbox](https://github.com/rejas/imagelightbox) and Bootstrap. I have a collapsed navbar in my mobile view and when the following Javascript is present on the page, the toggle-button is not working:

```
$( function() { 
$('a[data-imagelightbox="ufo"]').imageLightbox({button: true, quitOnDocClick: true, navigation: false, arrows: true, overlay: true, caption: true});
$('a[data-imagelightbox="dreifeld"]').imageLightbox({button: true, quitOnDocClick: true, navigation: false, arrows: true, overlay: true, caption: true});
$('a[data-imagelightbox="delle"]').imageLightbox({button: true, quitOnDocClick: true, navigation: false, arrows: true, overlay: true, caption: true});
 });
```

My html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="css/imagelightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/imagelightbox.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I don't assume that there is anything wrong with my navbar, as it is working, when the JavaScript above is not present.

Does someone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you recreate the same issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: try test.spannmacher.com

Comment: The toggle button is working there. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Can you check again? Maybe I was not uploading quick enough. Not working on my side in Microsoft Edge or iPhone. Edit: script is only present on front page, so its not working there.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the Developer of [Imagelightbox](https://github.com/rejas/imagelightbox). Turns out it was a bug in the plugin itself and it has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I analysed test.spannmacher.com The toggle button is not working.

This is due to the fact that bootstrap js is included in the head not in the body. When bootstrap js is executed it doesn't see any html tag and any button tag with data-toggle so the jquery selectors return empty array. As a quick proof if you copy past whole https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js code in console the navigation will start working.

P.S. Also you should not include js files in head(other than modernizer). This will stop web page rendering untill all js files are loaded. So put htem before closing body tag.

**Edit:**

Please use this order exactly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="css/imagelightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
<!-- html code goes here -->
    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/imagelightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I appreciate your effort!

Comment: Actually, I got optimistic to early. When I move everything but jquery down to the </body> tag, its still the same issue. As soon as I move jquery down to the rest, which means it is AFTER the script mentioned in OP, then the menu works again, but of course my lightbox won't work.

Comment: @mspann in your body tag jquery must come first and other plugins next to jquery. Because other plugins depend upon jquery. They need jquery first loaded. Also use defer on each plugin.

Comment: Using defer now and loading jquery first in <body>. No matter what I do, either the Menu or the lightbox work, but not both.